# Example of $f$ continuous on a totally bounded metric space $X$, where $f(X)$ isn't totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, complete-spaces

Let $X$ be a totally bounded metric space.  If $f$ is a uniformly continuous mapping from $X$ to a metric space $Y$, show that $f(X)$ is totally bounded.  Is the same true if $f$ is only required to be continuous?

I got the first part, but now I am stuck on the second part.  I think the answer is no and I think $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ with $X = (0,1]$ would be a counterexample, but I'm struggling showing that its not totally bounded

EDIT: Similarly, if $X$ is complete and $f$ continuous, is it true that $f(X)$ is complete?
Again, I think the answer is no, but I'm having trouble coming up with any example here

Comment: Hint: totally bounded $\implies$ bounded.

Comment: $f(0,1]=[1,\infty)$ is not bounded,leave totally bounded

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you!  I added a question. Could you please take a look at it

Comment: @Find_X Thank you!  I added a question. Could you please take a look at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\iota\colon[1,+\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $\iota(x)=\frac1x$. The space $[1,+\infty)$ is complete, $\iota$ is continuous, but $\iota\bigl([1,+\infty)\bigr)=(0,1]$, which is not complete.